# ASP. Net application is working fine with specified route url but not working with http://locahost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net application. The application is working when the url is http://locahost/device.aspx but not working when the given url is just http://locahost. It is throwing an IIS exception and the IIS image is displayed when http://locahost is given
[IIS image displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFaOC.png)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IIS, you need to set the default page in your IIS server. You can check the steps online as it varies from version to version.

Another way thorough `web.config`, you need to add following tag in your web.config file

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <defaultDocument enabled="true"> 
            <files> 
                <add value="device.aspx" /> 
            </files> 
        </defaultDocument> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that also before only then also its not working dude. Same application is running in many systems, only one system this problem exists

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have a default.aspx page.

IIS searchs the Default.aspx if you don't define in the url the page that you want to display . If Default.aspx doesn't exist, it can't decide which page to display.

If you don't have a Default aspx, you should add your device.aspx in the iis manager to your site like on the image.

First, you should open the iis manager (you can type Windows + R to execute the command inetmgr in order to open the iis manager).

Than you expand the server and Default Web site and choose your application.

Double click on the Default Documents and add a new default documents like on the image.

[image]

If you want to refer the default web site to your application in order to use only http://localhost url, you can configure your iis like on the second image

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried that also before only then also its not working dude, really confused  what to do

Comment: Did you  try to put your device.aspx to the top of the list on the default pages list on the iis manager ?

Comment: Yes  i tried that too, but also not working. Same application is running in many systems(without the device.aspx in default douments list), only in one system this problem exists even after adding the device.aspx

Comment: It is clear now with the image that you added. http://localhost doesn't refer to your application. Either you should add your application name to the url like http://localhost/myapplication or you should link the defaultwebsite to your application.

Comment: Can you please show me the details of how to do that whatever you have specified to link the default website to my application

Comment: Yes i checked your response now, But my application is directly under C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder . No more further folders to mention the appname

Comment: Did you add the device.aspx to default documents of the DefaultWebSite ?

Comment: I installed an older version of the same website and installed the new version now and the problem got fixed automatically, Thanks for your support dude learnt so many things from you